# Do animations apply changes over time or immediately?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am not very familiar with animations in Android. From what I gather there are 2 main types of animations.

1) View animations - animations that change how some view is drawn on screen **but not** the underlying view properties themselves

2) Property animations - animations that change how some view is drawn on screen **and** the underlying view properties themselves

I know that in IOS when an animation occurs (like a translation), the actual view properties themselves are changed immediately - and a "fake delayed rendering" is then shown to the user transitioning from how the view looked before the properties changed vs after the properties changed.

What about in Android? Do the values change at the start? Do the values change at the end? Do the values change in the middle continuously?

Comment: the values change for `Property animations` only - `View animations`, as you wrote, are used only for presentation purposes and dont contain well defined properties

Comment: @pskink If view animations don't change the actual values, then at what time does the view return to its "natural" form? during another `setContentView` in `onCreate`?

Comment: when the view animation ends

Comment: @pskink Does setting `fillEnabled`, `fillBefore`, `fillAfter` change this? Does it make a view animation into something that actually modifies the properties?

Comment: yes: `fill*` affect this somehow, but its better to use `property animations` to avoid any surprises (the easiest form is `android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator`)